# Drag & drop from WPF to different targets

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I have a WFP application with a tree where I can drag and drop objects around.

```
 DragDrop.DoDragDrop(dragSource, new DataObject(typeof(IFileObject), ((FilePresenter)dragSource.DataContext).FileObject), DragDropEffects.Move | DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

Each tree object also represents a file on my harddrive. I would like to be able to also drag that object from my WPF application to explorer (to create a copy) or maybe to Outlook to create an attachment.

I assume (probably wrongly) that it depends on the target what kind of DataObject I have to attach, but at the time of starting the drag I don't where the user will drop the DataObject.

I know that other applications can create different kind of drops. When I drag an e-mail in Outlook for example, i can move it to a different folder. Dragging it to the explorer will create a msg file. Dragging it to a text editor will insert the subject of the email as text.

**How do I have to initialize the `DragDrop.DoDragDrop(...)` to drag&drop inside my application by using my internal objects and outside my application to provide a filename?**

This is not a duplicate of [Can we drop a file in windows explorer from WPF window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165874/can-we-drop-a-file-in-windows-explorer-from-wpf-window) My question is how to support **BOTH** internal and external drag and drop (if possible at all).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we drop a file in windows explorer from WPF window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165874/can-we-drop-a-file-in-windows-explorer-from-wpf-window) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662509/drag-and-drop-files-into-wpf

Comment: @netaholic: Please read my question again. The first possible duplicate does not aim at supporting drag&drop internally and externally. The second question is about how to drop into WPF, which is not what I asked about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an answer in this Post: [c# Drag and Drop from my custom app to notepad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772102/c-sharp-drag-and-drop-from-my-custom-app-to-notepad)

To investigate the right format maybe it helps to drop some data from explorer to your application and try to build the data accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the proper duplicate (the answer there solved my problem). I will close this question.